# nginx 502 bad gateway error with Django webapp hosted on AWS EC2

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, django-wsgi

Ever since rebooting my Ubuntu EC2 instance, I have an issue with nginx giving a 502 error for my site. I didn't change any settings before the reboot and the site was working fine before then.

Error from `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2022/12/06 21:10:54 [error] 1503#1503: *4 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: ###.##.##.###, server: ##.#.###.###, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: "##.#.###.###", referrer: "http://##.#.###.###/"
```

Here is my config in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`:

```
server_tokens               off;
access_log                  /var/log/nginx/esms.access.log;
error_log                   /var/log/nginx/esms.error.log;

# This configuration will be changed to redirect to HTTPS later
server {
  server_name               .##.#.###.###;
  listen                    80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  }
  location /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/ubuntu/ESMS/esms/static/;
  }
}
```

And the output of `netstat -plnt`:

```
 sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      664/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1567/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      420/systemd-resolve 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      664/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1567/nginx: master
```

Comment: Is anything listening on port 8000?

Comment: you don't have anything running that is listening to port 8000. restart your django app

Comment: oh... i'm an idiot. I forgot that django will not just magically start on its own when the server is rebooted. It's working now! TYVM!    What's the best way to make django autostart when the server is rebooted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The django server wasn't running after reboot because it is not set up to autostart after reboot. Running the command `nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &` fixes it

Comment: How do you start the app ?
It usually starts on its own after deployment but upon a particular deployment it  is giving me the nginx error